# How would you generate brand new html files when users upload content?

Tags: php, html, css

I am in the process of creating my first website.  I want users to upload content and then redirect the viewer to a unique html file to show them that specific content.

I'm fairly new to web development and I'm trying to figure out if this is actually less complicated than I think it will be or not.

Example... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=adzYW5DZoWs&t=1s
When you click on any youtube video, they always start out the same way "/watch?v" followed by the extra bit at the end to distinguish itself from other videos.  I need something similar to this.  Where should I look/start to find out more?

Comment: in very simple terms: the part after `? ` sends parameters to a script, which then decides what to do with that/what content to show. And you don't need to genrerate html files, they are "generated" by the script as it sends them to the browser (so no *.html is ever stored as a file)

Comment: So I would need to learn javascript?  I found a way to generate files using php "fopen" im guessing this wouldn't be ideal

Comment: ad javascript: not yet neccessary for such basic functionality, no (but you will not get around it in long terms). ad fopen: only needed if you really wanna load different html files  - but I doubt you really want/need that.

Comment: What wold you suggest instead of javascript then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for a similar answer, try using the fopen function in php.

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_open.asp